# Eclipse Key Preferences; Debugging; Adding A "Watch Expression" Using The Keyboard

Tags: eclipse, debugging, keyboard-shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem With PHP Eclipse Key Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168966/problem-with-php-eclipse-key-binding)

How do I define a custom key binding in eclipse?

I have to admit, for a FREE PRODUCT, Eclipse really delivers.  However, sometimes I have to scratch my head about certain missing features...

Eclipse has over ELEVEN HUNDRED different key bindings.

[image]
<sub>(source: [rigel222.com](http://www.rigel222.com/Eclipse_KeyBindings.jpg))</sub>

I would like to use one of those KeyBindings to add a "Watch" Expression to the expressions window, while debugging.

[image]
<sub>(source: [rigel222.com](http://www.rigel222.com/Eclipse_RightClick.jpg))</sub>

Here is an additional screenshot showing that I already understand the "filter" process.  I have set key-bindings for everything I could find pertaining to "Watch", but as you can see it doesn't show up in my right-click menu, and does not function when I use the defined keyboard shortcut.

[image]
<sub>(source: [rigel222.com](http://www.rigel222.com/eclipsewatch.jpg))</sub>

Despite the prevailing opinion that this is "blatant whining", It is also a legitimate problem for me.

Please help.

Comment: this "question" is more complaining than asking something.

Comment: This question could be compressed to "How do I define a custom key binding in eclipse?". Was the eclipse bashing really necessary?

Comment: If you are insecure about your pet IDE being criticized, then by all means, step up and defend it.  How do I define a custom key binding in eclipse?

Comment: Bozho, this is only a complaint if a key-binding for "add watch" cannot be accomplished in Eclipse.  Is that what your saying.  If not then my question is pretty clear.  Maybe you need a few more screenshots?

Answer (score 4):

I just tried it and it works: In the given dialog I entered the word `watch` as the filter text. The list of key bindings was reduced to three elements. I chose `watch` and gave a new key binding and it worked.

**EDIT:**

Please try to unbind the other key bindings that occupy <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> or give `Watch` another unique key binding.

Comment: +1 for constructive feedback even in the face of blatant whining.

Comment: What is a "given" dialog.  What "filter text" are you talking about?

Comment: I assume "given" = "the dialog you showed", and "filter text" - well, chec the text boxes in your screenshot and you'll find it.

Comment: You apparently click the filter button and a text box comes up allowing you to filter the list.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  Toggle Watchpoint doesn't have the expected functionality.

Comment: Please refer to the added (third) image.  Maybe this is only an issue in Eclipse for PHP?