# PHP Eclipse - add Key Binding for Watch

Tags: php, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I have to admit, for a FREE PRODUCT, Eclipse really delivers.  However, sometimes I don't understand certain missing features...

Eclipse has over ELEVEN HUNDRED different key bindings.

[image]
<sub>(source: [rigel222.com](http://www.rigel222.com/Eclipse_KeyBindings.jpg))</sub>

I would like to use one of those KeyBindings to add a "Watch" Expression to the expressions window, while debugging.

[image]
<sub>(source: [rigel222.com](http://www.rigel222.com/Eclipse_RightClick.jpg))</sub>

Here is an additional screenshot showing that I already understand the "filter" process.  I have set key-bindings for everything I could find pertaining to "Watch", but as you can see it doesn't show up in my right-click menu, and does not function when I use the defined keyboard shortcut.

[image]
<sub>(source: [rigel222.com](http://www.rigel222.com/eclipsewatch.jpg))</sub>

Despite the prevailing opinion that this is "blatant whining", It is also a legitimate problem for me.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The menu item you seek is filtered out by default from the view. There is a filter button near the lower right corner of the window. There you should uncheck the "Filter uncategorized commands" checkbox, and then searching for watch should produce Add to Watch, Add Watch Expression output. I'm not entirely sure these are the ones you need, but it might work.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I didn't know about the uncategorized commands.  Unfortunately, after having set key bindings for absolutely everything in the list for "watch", it still doesn't work.  Does anyone else out there have PHP Eclipse?  Are you able to add a watch expression without right-clicking?